# Are circular references supported when using class expressions?

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I am having some problems working with circular references when using class expressions. I am dynamically generating classes and trying to correclty type them.

Circular references work fine with class declarations.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

```js
// Works
class X {
  y?: Y;
}
class Y {
  x?: X;
}

// Works without circular ref
const I = class {
};
const J = class {
  i?: typeof I;
};


// Doesn't work  with circular ref
const A = class {
  b?: typeof B;
};
const B = class {
  a?: typeof A;
};
```

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHUHsCcGsGcBQBjANgQ3vUANUBvRUUATwH4AuUATQG5EBfFDLGgo0AD0t3qcRAQYCUAHcAlgBcAFpACuk0MnHRkcjNFDQApgDMUkAHbxFASVABeJS2yEG9ZEZOgAUpeuZbHcT0kkADtqQuqCmfPSIAmAAIpDa8IYA5IqiwsQSMkoqahpaegbGigCC7mie7MQARr4BQSEAQuEFzvWlNhWg6DWBwaBFTUA)

---

**Update for context**

I am trying to create a function that generates a class from a given "model definition". This model definition has types like boolean, string, number but could also have a relation to another model.

It works fine in term of types as long as circular references are not introduced.

This [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygxgC2BAhgFQJ4AdgGcoDeAUFLGgEoCSAcgOJQC8UARLgC4BOAliAObMAaElGoBVALIAhAKLlGLcBABGwDoOGSA8poAy0gILV5zJQHtTAG2AoQzIgF8ibbMCjiUWeElSYc+JsSkANpeyOguuAB0MBQ0tAC6AFxQ7Nx8ANzCIYhhvniRYlKySVCKKhyZwaE+EZFaugbUJWaW1iCZ9pnOOFAAYlzAFgAmACJ4cNxYbKYc8gDWwBimAGZuHtXhflAAPm6mQ4MAwqYgqWBw0xwAPDYYAHxdLnsHFmO4E1xTM-LkwHAzQyuqR4vAEfQGwzeHy+HAeTie4n2g0opzYNjgwCuIygwAAHmxQEN8IiXlDJpc7vJAlAggBpKA8KALJarEYlEZ0+I4-GE-DMlZrTw5Gp+YSkAD8go2eVwQQ5tPi8TFUGSAAp5Vy8QSQETnkcTmcLjMrjxlqooGhKZK0CrSsAAG6qACUDkePRJ+tRHHOlyuNq1vL1FhR7HRmNud0pAWEIGAAHcoKqnck0B1MkQAPQZqD6KDLMAgC5cE5QNgIFBsUsoBb4FBQCBIixQA7LHhcNjFkBQGxDKAcYBsMAcU7dqBwCwoXD4ZbfMsV5vAVsgdudoj-VFj-sV4CHCdT3ocUwQMZLlclphY7na3Ue17jckzO6q4QN0mLtsdk7JEZEJ2MSnUv2g7DmOe74NSpDroalxJoQyqkJoSgAFZ-GwkTMrgqqvoMJ4fp2TqRDOHDSCgiCqsy-5waQ1HUVYlZ4SgFgAGqMWAwCVDR1G4HG7aIIm2F3qen4gEEzLxH+EGcZBk6uNKtT1HohiJPBUkMsuHaMSxFhsfIyyMbg7EqVJShbnMHGqWOMmwMKmz5IUMjkMpFk0QxzGsa4TAAAzmc5JnWGZRnUXAVlyX40SxHQTnOaQrlaTpTDMMwPkWX51bJdRjiBYhKEXJELY8MAAAKh44BwziqmWXC4GCzJgpJUmgJAqgoEoVjJJwbFCNFcbcGirXAO13rAF1zn2u5ySxe5gX2E66UzT5jikPY3bEo2xxej6xq3iGaKFpiIyRmmRCZtmogwPotDSMpUGVreACM8gTNYBK7pOuAHkeuHqZ2qrUq2gxDHdyShfkMRUHQI3-cMABMwM2TKdTaIp1AjVm9aNrDQbQ1AaNwFwHBwGAE6zP2yz4HGJwAOSVhTHBzFAPFlqBb3clg-ZTp2+CJKqiZoEgGDNqYDPtggzNTgu44oBwFacy681rgat0Y49W4vWBH3Hu+30nL9whQ4DcPeLZUT2bIkMQkMmMg1EYNxCNAlA0Gd0OLNx1o3zeCuDwoZ7bW-ali4vakf8HBDCCpZC2Wrj5drXYtaYjond2OpqSujFcAAXsAvaM6LLYoETlZjdpeDdnAIdh3wEelkg+MB6KN3oy8d07WG8ixgm91JpkjcCdDrd7e38ZY93bvZgA6q4eB9RYVWi3W-YTsJuAIJ8RB9wPGKRA78gO5vhkK6crSRLwh5gFgo9QcfFimLwv1QJEj976ibfy1fViRDfd8EA-T8Y-vUA34GmPqfUw59pA6lHuvRsLcX57UIhbB6CVcBHlcMXNiSVoEvH7nAre+skFQAACzQ3TO-YAJ8z4X1dmQz+t976P23jAgBQCj4fy-vQv+2DmHUOAR-UB4DIGuyAA) illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: can you provide a little bit more of context? you cannot declare dynamic types, you can use generics though, but in any case with typescript the idea is to model statically your data, and the possible variations.

Comment: I've edited the question to show an example with a class expression with no circular ref. Take a look at the linked playground to see for yourself

Comment: I think we might be falling in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) , what are you trying to accomplish? maybe we could model in another way with typescript.

Comment: I've updated the question to add more context, hopefully it is not a "XY problem"

Comment: Ok, so i think the problem is called "cyclical dependency", you can design around it or know how to deal with it according to your domain.

I think a common pattern is instantiate both models and make the association after. 
```ts
const model1Instance = new Model1();
model1Instance.associateWith(model2Instance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having researched a bit in the TypeScript Language Specification, I think  that unfortunately it is not possible to use circular type references with class expressions.

I cannot judge from your given information if your general approach is correct - e.g. if you really need class expressions, dynamic models or it is a XY problem. That's another topic for itself. What I try here is to answer, why your approach with circular type references and class expressions creates compile errors.

When class expressions `A` and `B` reference each other by `typeof A`/ `typeof B`, you create type aliases with the `typeof` operator. For type aliases, the specs say:

> It is an error for the type specified in a type alias to depend on that type alias. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#310-type-aliases)

However, the following is also stated:

> Note that object type literals, function type literals, and constructor type literals do not depend on types referenced within them and are therefore permitted to circularly reference themselves through type aliases. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#310-type-aliases)

I interpret the statement in this way: If you wrap/substitute your model references in one of above mentioned type literals, it's fine to have circular references.

[Modified Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygxgC2BAhgFQJ4AdgGcoDeAUFLGgEoCSAcgOJQC8UARLgC4BOAliAObMAaElGoBVALIAhAKLlGLcBABGwDoOGSA8poAy0gILV5zJQHtTAG2AoQzIgF8ibbMCjiUWeElSYc+JsSkANpeyOguuAB0MBQ0tAC6AFxQ7Nx8ANzCIYhhvniRYlKySVCKKhyZwaE+EZFaugbUJWaW1iCZ9pnOOFAAYlzAFgAmACJ4cNxYbKYc8gDWwBimAGZuHtXhflAAPlAAFHsAlIwAfG6mQ4MAwqYgqWBw0xwAPDYYJ4eZTi7nlxZjuAmXCmM3k5GAcBmQ2eqR4vAEfQGwwBQJBHBOX26rnEF0GlDubBscGAzxGUGAAA82KAhvgcX8UZMnmcAlkANJQHhQBZLVYjEojIJs+Lkqk0-A8lZrTw5Gp+YSkAD80o2eVwQUFwviCqgyT2mpFlOpIFp+2ODDO9Out3ujxmzx4y1UUDQZ2VaF1pWAADdVIcHF0flaLDcCRwHk9nh6jeLfniCUSSW8TizCMIQMAAO5m5JoDpfAD0Bag+igyzAIEeXFuUDYCBQbFrKAW+BQUAguIsUEuyx4XDY1ZAUBsQygHGAbDAHDuw6gcAsKFw+GWoLrDe7wF7IH7g6IkIJc-HDeAVwXS96HFMEDGW53NaYpNFxtNwcZwOZe2EHYZm77A9uyQjEQ5pnIEY4TlOQ7zou+BgaQ+62k8RxpqQqFQJoSgAFYQmwkQ8rgezfoMN5-oOhyRCuHDSCgiB7DypwoWhqFWI2pEoBYABq7FgMAlRMaQuCZv2iD7ER-y-tu-4gEEPLxMccH8XOi6uKqtT1HohiJDqimcpJXDsVxFg8fIyzsbgvHaYpShHnMfE6XAymwLKmz5IUMjkFpOloWxnHca4TAAAx2V51nWLZlloQ55lOd4LlRDEVB0J5XmkD5hnGUwzDMMFOmhc2OWoY4EXoVhOGRD2PDAAACpeOAcM4ex1lwuAIjyCIKfxoCQKoKBKFYyScDxQgpZm3CEn1wADeGwDDV53p+ckaV+cV9ifJZq3BY4pD2MOdKdqGiH2sG+LsImpIpvmRBEEWUCiDA+i0NIWkIY2EzWNSwYAIzyMhFqHu9J5nrgF5XiRem3HsYG9oMQyfckql+NEsR0LN0PDAATPDzlqnU2gadQs1iZj-3HsG6NQA4a0vSTH2duTTC-Wcb3HqeMEg9eEl3iAkPCGjsNY7FONubIqNIkMxMI-kCVxITnZwzTwBfZThbFmgSDRTwp2Vngw7jrWLijjRkIcEMcK1qYtZIBut5ScOZi+tdxYjrpO7sVwABewCjkJdbWygYAWI281GTrRtQmb0yW8AXCzFiuB7jajZiZ9J2Etr8gZtmezM7TfyfUchxHJk1NE6niYZ1m+w54rdMF0XV03QA6q4eDjRYzUILO44LlJuAIMCRClwm2uRMn8jJ2X2uZBPw-EqPdPj3Tk-El8CGtJEvCXmAWD12vViRBYpi8JDUCRGfM9a8SUAbQndzr4fx8EKf59L7Prg33vwAb1vWDSCa9eDzlsvL+fNvqZVwFeVwwceLZUAX8dGwCKJizAVAAALOjVeNp16b1MNvXeWD94PxPmfeeedgHXypgQr+RCn4kKHpfd+lC777xwdvP+Qx65AA)

In this sample I wrapped your model class construction in a factory method /function type literal. It is just for demonstration purpose and works, feel free to interpret it your own way.

It presumes you can adjust `FieldDescriptor` slightly:

```
type FieldDescriptor = keyof MapSchemaTypes | (() => ModelConstructor<any>);
```

Concerning class declarations: I suppose they work in your example as class declarations and interfaces are supported as [Recursive Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3118-recursive-types). See also [this statement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540) from the TypeScript chief developer.

Hope, thats throws a bit light on your case.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a statically typed language, meaning you have to define the types before hand,you cannot dynamically generate types, however, you can use Generics to achieve your goal.